# How to avoid accidentally taking an array element by value instead of by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

Say I have an array `std::vector<Foo>`, and I want to iterate over all my foos and do stuff do them like so:

```
for (auto foo : vecFoo)
    foo.x = 10;
```

This ends up doing nothing because it's making a local copy of the contents of vecFoo instead of a reference to it. The correct loop is as follows:

```
for (auto& foo : vecFoo)
    foo.x = 10;
```

This is a mistake I've made a few times now, so I'd like to find a solution for it that will catch me when I get it wrong. I would be happy with either something I can do to the struct or a warning flag I can turn on. I've tried making `Foo`'s copy constructor private, but then I end up being unable do `push_back` or `emplace_back`, which is clearly not what I want.

Comment: Experience and muscle memory

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - and unit tests.

Comment: We have things like scoped_ptr for people who can't remember to delete their pointers at the end of a function, I'm asking for some mechanism for people like me who don't always remember the tiny little & in the loop. A mechanical solution would be nice.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a static code analysis tool. I don't know of any that can do this (not that I know such tools well), but you could probably implement it as addition rule on [cpplint.py](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py) easily enough.

Comment: For you example - use `std::fill`. Problem gone! :-)

Comment: `emplace_back` shouldn't use a copy constructor, it should use the move constructor.

Comment: @jrok: that only solves the trivial example I gave above, I want a general solution.

Comment: @Alex: The problem is that whether you want a reference or a copy depends on usage, and both are valid in the language. You cannot tell the compiler: *please ignore that this is valid and generate an error because I tend to forget*. Again, the most important thing is to *learn* to add the `&`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: *strangely* enough `emplace_back` does need a *copy-constructor* (if the type does not have a `nothrow` *move-constructor*) as it might need to grow the buffer. (Hint: *nothrow move-constructor* is an important bit of information). Then again, this is not a valid generic solution, it only applies when you can modify the stored type

Comment: If you're making this mistake a lot, stop using the auto keyword.  Just because a language has a feature it doesn't mean you have to use it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh I did not know that at all. That's the second completely new thing I've learned today.

Comment: @David: Right, I understand that. What I am asking for is a way to make that copy not valid for my class so that the opportunity to make such a mistake is not made.

Comment: @Alex: For a class that falls 100% under your control, you can hack the compiler into rejecting the code (I have provided a description as an answer --well, also as a comment above), but that will not help you if the stored type is out of your control.

Comment: Add to build process and check: `grep -P '\bfor\s*\(\s*auto\s*[^&]' *.cc`

Comment: That will catch cases where I have std::vector<Foo*> which I suppose it technically okay, but unnecessary.

Comment: @Alex: "*What I am asking for is a way to make that copy not valid for my class so that the opportunity to make such a mistake is not made.*" If that's what you're asking for, then you should *ask for that*. Your question mentions *nothing* about making your class uncopyable.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: That is only one possible solution to the problem I posted, by no means was it the only possible solution. That comment wasn't my actual question, but a reply to David clarifying one possible solution I was pursuing. Also, I did mention a failed attempt at making it uncopyable by making the copy constructor private.

Comment: You can use `auto&&` as the 'default', but it's a tradeoff as you *will* need to think about those times when you really want `auto`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the underlying problem is *learning*. If you make the mistake a couple more times you will end up learning from experience.

As of language tricks for your particular case, where you have full control over the type that is stored in the container, you can provide a `nothrow` move constructor and disable copy construction. That will require the use of `emplace_back` (or *move semantics* with `push_back`).

Still, this is only a way of triggering an error in this particular case, but if you store any type that is not 100% under your control (i.e. cannot disable copy construction or add move construction, or cannot implement a nothrow move constructor --cannot guarantee that it will not throw) then you are out of luck, which leads to the first sentence: *learn to use references*

Comment: @Xeo: That is an interesting idea. I would not do it, but it is nonetheless an interesting idea. Note that the wrapper must still offer the same properties: no copy constructor (easy) and nothrow move constructor. The second is a bit trickier. Consider that the copy constructor of the wrapped type can throw, then you cannot provide a wrapper that implements a *heavy* move by copying the internal object, so you would have to wrap a pointer (which is trivial to offer the nothrow move constructor). Then the memory layout of the application changes and you'll need to update the code...

Comment: ... and you end up breaking the design just because you don't want to have to *remember* whether you want to iterate over a container copying or holding references. Do you really want to go through this refactor just not to have to remember to write an ampersand? I don't.

Comment: Obviously, I'd write an ampersand over this convoluted workaround any day, but I like strange ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

> This is a mistake I've made a few times now, so I'd like to find a solution for it that will catch me when I get it wrong.

In my experience, the best solution is to train yourself to always declare objects as `const` by default. This makes it a compiler-checked error to try to modify them. *Once you do that*, the compiler will catch such a declaration for you when you have forgotten to deviate from it to make an object writeable:

```
// This is what my hands write by default:
int const x = 42;
```

I try to always write like this. Then, whenever I see the following in code:

```
int y =  42;
```

My mind tries to figure out if the variable should actually be modifiable. You can adapt this thinking to your loop example because thankfully, C++11 allows this for range-for loops as well:

```
for (auto const i : vecFoo)
    i.foo = 10; // error
```

Of course this only works once you’ve trained yourself to automatically `const` everything.

I agree that this is a far cry from perfect and requires considerable exercise. As several people have repeatedly noted, the best solution would be for C++ to consider declarations `const` by default (and in fact at least for lambda-captured values this *is the case*) but that ship has sailed.

Comment: I think he _wants_ the `i.foo = 10` to work, but it's not working because he's making a copy of the object with `auto` instead of a reference with `auto&`.

Comment: @Seth Sure. But once you train yourself to always write `const` by default, the compiler will subsequently complain if you have forgotten to make an object a (mutable) reference *instead of* a `const`). This requires a considerable bit of mental training to get into the habit of `const`ing everything but I don’t know a better way. See update. Hopefully this makes it clearer. And yes, it’s not a particularly good solution.

Comment: I think you misread my question, this doesn't solve my problem at all. The problem is not const-ness, its that i is a copy rather than a reference to a value in vecFoo.

Comment: Should be: static const unsigned int x = 42; :)

Comment: @Alex I haven’t misread it. And I agree that the solution is rotten but it works (and it has the benefit of making the code more explicit and thus more amenable to automated error checking): train yourself to *always* declare variables `const`. Then, if you want to modify a variable, you make a mental effort to get the declaration right because otherwise the compiler complains.

Comment: @Mustafa No, why should it? The 42 is just an example. It’s a general pattern, I don’t only do it for compile-time constants. The whole point is doing it consistently *everywhere*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're making a good point about using the const keyword.  I'm trying to make the point that you can take your example further (and you should).  You probably don't 42 added to the stack every time the function is called: make it static.  You can also use pointer arithmetic to modify that 'const' value in stack but you cannot when it is a const segment (causes sigsegv).  42 is an unsigned integer and never will be signed: use unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am asking for is a way to make that copy not valid for my class so that the opportunity to make such a mistake is not made.

C++11 makes it easy to make your class uncopyable. Just delete the copy constructor/assignment operator (assuming your compiler supports that C++11 feature):

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
  SomeClass(const SomeClass &) = delete;
  SomeClass &operator=(const SomeClass &) = delete;

...
};
```

Any attempt to call the copy constructor will yield a compiler error. If you're using Visual Studio, which doesn't yet support this syntax, you'll have to use the standard C++03 idioms for this. Namely, declaring the copy constructor privately.

---

> I can no longer use my struct in vectors since it can not be copied into the vector.

Sure you can. You just can't use functions that require *copying*. You have to replace your uses of `push_back` and `insert` with `emplace_back` and `emplace`.

Remember: if you declare a copy constructor and assignment operator, even just to delete them, you *must* manually declare a *move* constructor/assignment operator. Of course, you can use `= default` syntax.

Comment: This appears to fail for the same reason making the copy constructor private fails as mentioned in the question: I can no longer use my struct in vectors since it can not be copied into the vector.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then (or there is a bug in g++) because I can not get it to work. [This](http://pastebin.com/JCCPRjUK) does not compile for me. I get [these errors](http://pastebin.com/527hZ4Cr).

Comment: Thank you, that was the piece of the puzzle that I was missing.